# session In proc store location with taking space

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-2.0, asp.net-4.0

I am using session Inproc and hosted application on webserver
how can I check total space taken by user session. I need to
check for all user ie 69 user logged in on my server and acce
ssing site then 70 session is present on server I want to 
find out how much space they took and how can I compress or 
reduced size of session

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out size of session in ASP.NET from web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198082/how-to-find-out-size-of-session-in-asp-net-from-web-application)