# Size of Session Memory used by Entire website

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, session-variables

I want to know the size of memory used by session state variables including all the sessions present in AppDomain. I got the size of session variable that present in that session. But i want for entire AppDomain.

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of Application Domain Resource Monitoring you can find the memory usage by application domain. follow this link

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997285.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to loop through the session objects and get the total as mentioned in this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198082/how-to-find-out-size-of-session-in-asp-net-from-web-application).

Comment: This will only show the session of the user requesting this page, not all users.