# Find size of HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: c#, session

I have a web application that creates an object on page load and adds that object into the session by using HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(Obj). The Object includes a connection to Sql Server of the type SqlConnection.

What I want to do is to find out how big is the session at anytime during runtime. This is so that I can track how much memory is used at any time. I would like to also track the size of the object, and size of the sql connection.

I am clueless about looking for the right answer in the Internet. It seems I can't find what I am looking for. Found something like this: [How to find out size of session in ASP.NET from web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198082/how-to-find-out-size-of-session-in-asp-net-from-web-application) which I doubt gives me the right I answer. It seems like it gives the size of the session id string.

Comment: You need to search "how to find size of object in memory" . You can also use Count of the session items.

Comment: You can also configure stateserver if you are concerned about memory.