# java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.ehcache.Cache in Spring Webflow project

Tags: jsf, ehcache, spring-webflow

I'm migrating our jsf project to Spring Webflow + JSF. We use ehcache to store information about chat and users data. Dpwb class(serialized) pulls data from the ehcache. As long the Dpwb class is serialized it should work, why it is looking for serializing ehcache which I can't do anything about it.

**flow.xml**

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="wbIdentifiers" class="com.emyed.whiteboard.controller.WhiteboardIdentifiers" />
    <view-state id="createWb" view="createdialog.xhtml">
        <transition on="create" to="wboard">
            <evaluate expression="generalCreateWhiteboard.create()"
                result="wbIdentifiers" />
        </transition>
    </view-state>


    <view-state id="wboard" view="/WEB-INF/views/D/whiteboard.xhtml">
        <on-render>
            <evaluate expression="generalCreateWhiteboard.setDisplayWhiteboard(wbIdentifiers)"  result="viewScope.dpwb "></evaluate>
        </on-render>
    </view-state>

</flow>
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:171)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.ehcache.Cache
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:422)
    org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap.writeObject(LocalAttributeMap.java:327)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:422)
    org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap.writeObject(LocalAttributeMap.java:327)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowSessionImpl.writeExternal(FlowSessionImpl.java:160)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1398)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:943)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.writeExternal(FlowExecutionImpl.java:309)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1398)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.serialize(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:173)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:70)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:171)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception indicates that one of the objects that WebFlow is trying to serialize has an instance variable (or contains another object with instance variable) of type `net.sf.ehcache.Cache`, which is not serializable. Note that it is not enough just to mark an object as `java.io.Serializable`, all of its serialized members must also be serializable.

This question describes a test that you can use to check whether something is really serializable (the instance variables must be populated for the test to be meaningful):

[how to test in Java that a class implements Serializable correctly (not just is an instance of Serializable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840356/how-to-test-in-java-that-a-class-implements-serializable-correctly-not-just-is)

From your flow definition, it looks like `com.emyed.whiteboard.controller.WhiteboardIdentifiers` must be serializable because it is stored in the flow scope.

From what I can see, it doesn't look like the "Dpwb" class needs to be serializable because it is only stored in the view scope, which doesn't require serializability.