# How to unit test serialization with invariant checking?

Tags: java, unit-testing, serialization

I have an immutable class with invariant checking. According to Effective Java 2nd Ed item 76 it has a readObjects method that throws an InvalidObjectException if the deserialized object violates the invariants:

```
// readObject method with validity checking
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    s.defaultReadObject();

    // Check that our invariants are satisfied
    if (/* some condition*/)
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Invariant violated");
}
```

I know how to [test serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840356/how-to-test-in-java-that-a-class-implements-serializable-correctly-not-just-is), but this tests only the happy path. There is an ugly way of triggering the InvalidObjectException, where you hardcode a tampered byte stream (shamelessly stolen from [EJ2 item 76](http://books.google.ch/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=bloch+effective+java+bogusperiod&source=bl&ots=yYLjLnu6M_&sig=EAQ5hHx0gAXDa96K74cltbtyFdo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ztIcU-z7OKToywOiuYLIAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bloch%20effective%20java%20bogusperiod&f=false)):

```
public class BogusPeriod {
    // manipulated byte stream
    private static final byte[] serializedForm = new byte[] {
        (byte)0xac, (byte)0xed, 0x00, 0x05, /* ca. 100 more bytes omitted */ };

    // Returns the object with the specified serialized form
    private static Object deserializeBogusPeriod() {
        try {
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedForm);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
            return ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is really ugly and will probably break as soon as the serializable class changes.
I wonder if there is a simpler method of creating test cases like that? Maybe there is a library that knows at which offsets of a byte stream specific values are located to allow tampering at run time?

Answer (score 1):

You assume, that the object/class is deserializable from java (non corrupt data) and want to do some checks afterwards (like if a date in a string is formatted correct).

Writing your unit test for this, you could use a library like Serialysis (https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/06/12/disassembling-serialized-java-objects) to check generated byte streams by rightful streamed objects, find out where in the byte stream your data is located and modify your data during test setup.

THOUGH

*IF* you trust the source of your data you receive and have been able to deserialize, better use some kind of interceptor / validator provided by your framework of choice (Spring in SE, Java EE etc.) at the moment the object reaches your application.

Comment: +1 for Serialysis, though I still need to figure out if it can help me. And: never trust a data source ;-)