# How can this code throw a NoWhenBranchMatchedException?

Tags: android, kotlin, sealed-class

In our most recent app release we see a handful `kotlin.NoWhenBranchMatchedException`s reported to Fabric/Crashlytics.

This is the code snippet in question:

```
private lateinit var welcome: Welcome

// ...

welcome.welcomeStateLoginStatus.let {
    val handled = when (it) {
        UnknownUser -> {
            btn_login.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btn_logout.visibility = View.GONE

            secondButtonFocusedInfoText = getString(R.string.welcome_login_button_info)
            tv_user_description.text = null
        }
        is InternalUser -> {
            btn_login.visibility = View.GONE
            btn_logout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            secondButtonFocusedInfoText = "Logout"
            tv_user_description.text = "Logged in as internal user"
        }
        ExternalUser -> {
            btn_login.visibility = View.GONE
            btn_logout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            secondButtonFocusedInfoText = "Logout"
            tv_user_description.text = "Logged in as external user"
        }
    }
}
```

And the class definitions:

```
data class Welcome(val welcomeStateLoginStatus: WelcomeStateLoginStatus, val userCanBuySubscription: UserCanBuySubscription? = null) : WelcomeState()

sealed class WelcomeStateLoginStatus() : Serializable
object UnknownUser : WelcomeStateLoginStatus()
data class InternalUser(var user: User) : WelcomeStateLoginStatus()
object ExternalUser : WelcomeStateLoginStatus()
```

I am puzzled as to how this code can even *theoretically* throw that exception - as you can see we even introduced the `handled` value just to force the compiler to make sure that all cases are handled...

Comment: No 'is' before `UnknownUser` and `ExternalUser`?

Comment: These are `object`s, not `data class`es, so the `is` is not needed.

Comment: I bet this error come from the `: Serializable` and no [`serialVersionUID`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it). Each subclass has a `serialVersionUID` different.

Comment: @LionelBriand: Thank you very much, a colleague also just suggested something along these lines - will look into that!

Comment: @LionelBriand: So, @Hong Duan's suggestion of doing `is` checks instead of equality checks for the `object`s would actually solve the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Serialization was indeed the problem:

```
package com.drei.tv.ui.welcome

import junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import java.io.*


class WelcomeStateLoginStatusTest {

    @Test
    fun testSerialization() {
        val original: UnknownUser = UnknownUser

        val copy: UnknownUser = unpickle(pickle(original), UnknownUser::class.java)

        println("singleton: $UnknownUser")
        println("original: $original")
        println("copy: $copy")

        val handled1 = when (copy) {
            original -> println("copy matches original")
            else -> println("copy does not match original")
        }

        val handled2 = when (copy) {
            is UnknownUser -> println("copy is an instance of UnknownUser")
            else -> println("copy is no instance of UnknownUser")
        }

        assertEquals(original, copy)
    }

    private fun <T : Serializable> pickle(obj: T): ByteArray {
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val oos = ObjectOutputStream(baos)
        oos.writeObject(obj)
        oos.close()
        return baos.toByteArray()
    }

    private fun <T : Serializable> unpickle(b: ByteArray, cl: Class<T>): T {
        val bais = ByteArrayInputStream(b)
        val ois = ObjectInputStream(bais)
        val o = ois.readObject()
        return cl.cast(o)
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
singleton: com.drei.tv.ui.welcome.UnknownUser@75828a0f
original: com.drei.tv.ui.welcome.UnknownUser@75828a0f
copy: com.drei.tv.ui.welcome.UnknownUser@5f150435
copy does not match original
copy is an instance of UnknownUser

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :com.drei.tv.ui.welcome.UnknownUser@75828a0f
Actual   :com.drei.tv.ui.welcome.UnknownUser@5f150435
```

As for **solutions**: Either implement `Serializable` properly or just use an `is` check instead of an equality check.

Thanks to Lionel Briand and Hong Duan for pointing us in the right direction and to Jason S for the code of `pickle` and `unpickle` posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840817/763935)

Answer (score 0):

I have just bumped into this question and cannot see the way we solved this in the answers. Although it is an old question, putting solution here just in case it helps people searching.

What we do is, eg for UnknownUser :

```
object UnknownUser : WelcomeStateLoginStatus() {
    private fun readResolve(): Any = UnknownUser
}
```

"The readResolve() method is part of the contract between the class itself and the Java serialiser. Just as the serialiser can invoke a private constructor, or will also detect and invoke (if present) the readResolve() method during deserialisation.

In this case we implement readResolve() to return the singleton. "

There is a detailed explanation why this is needed here:https://blog.stylingandroid.com/kotlin-serializable-objects/