# How to add existing complex objects to memcached?

Tags: c#, caching, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have a requirement where I need to implement memcached (Amazon.ElasticCache and Enyim Cache) with my existing .NET project. There are lot of existing complex objects in the project which i need to store in the cache. what I realzied is that, i need to implement **ISerializable** and decorate class with [Serializable] attribute. There are lot of Classes in my project which gonna be a tedious task for me implement ISerializable.

I tired just with **[Serializable]** attribute but it's not adding to cache.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Do you have an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while trying to connect with Memcached. You need to make sure all your objects are serializable by using the attribute [Serializable].

Also make sure, it is working with a unit test. More details about testing serialization can be found here - [How to unit test if my object is really serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236599/how-to-unit-test-if-my-object-is-really-serializable) .

Then set up a local memcached server and make sure the connection and data transfer is working. You can mock Amazon Elastic Cache by using this library - https://github.com/hybridtechie/fake-elasticache-.NET-version

Hope this helps